# Flexbox layout multiple items wrapping around a big one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to have a layout like the following image using flexbox:

[image]

I have tried the following but no luck so far:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
}

.flex-item:not(:first-child) {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-item:first-child {
  width: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">item 1(long)</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 4</div>  
</div>
```

I need the DOM structure to be like this, otherwise, I already know how to achieve this with nested elements.

Comment: Why Flex specifically ? As you already know it has limitations and it won't easy to control.

Comment: Doesn't have to be flexbox, it can be inline-block.

Answer (score 1):

[CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) would be more appropriate.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  text-align: center;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 50%;
}

.flex-item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 2;
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  background: pink;
}

.flex-item2 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1 / 2;
  background: lightcoral;
}

.flex-item3 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 2 / 3;
  background: lemonchiffon;
}

.flex-item4 {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 3 / 4;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item1">item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item2">item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item3">item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item4">item 4</div>
</div>
```

Although you can do it with Flexbox.
It makes more sense to me to make a small change to the DOM structure.
Your items 2, 3, 4 would be wrapped in an other Flex container.

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-itemA {
  width: 25%;
  background: pink;
}

/* Flex-itemB and Flex container itself for the next 3 elements */

.flex-itemB {
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: lightblue;
}

.flex-itemB1,
.flex-itemB2 {
  height: 25%;
}

.flex-itemB1 {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.flex-itemB2 {
  background: lemonchiffon;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-itemA">item A</div>
  <div class="flex-itemB">
    <div class="flex-itemB1">item B1</div>
    <div class="flex-itemB2">item B2</div>
    <div class="flex-itemB3">item B3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT based on @lawrence-witt answer**

Or if you really want to keep the DOM structure that way and use Flexbox and not Grid. Then you could do it like @lawrence-witt suggested.
I kept the :nth-child selectors although it would be easy to add a class for each element and avoid increasing the [specificity](https://csswizardry.com/2014/07/hacks-for-dealing-with-specificity/).

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: #323232;
  font-weight: 300;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 90%;
  height: 50%;
  margin: 2rem 5%;
  text-align: center;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  background: pink;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(n + 2) {
  width: 75%;
  /* This will make the height = 25% since the last element will have flex-grow: 1 */
  flex: 0.5;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3) {
  background: lemonchiffon;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(4) {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">item 1</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Wildhammer If you need the height of the parent container to be unset, just remove the rule from the code. It's here only to give it a bit of bigger height because there's no content yet.

Comment: In your snippet using grid, it would be better to have just 2 columns and 3 rows . This way you match the visual design, and it is easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using your DOM structure but I doubt it will be particularly useful, and as others have said, you're better off using Grid or even just inline elements. The trouble is you are trying to mix two layout contexts and flexbox isn't really built for that.

Give the container a explicit height and the wider elements a `flex:1` property, which will make them grow to fill the remaining space. I used `nth-child` as it is more readable to me and your original code didn't actually behave as you intended when put into codepen.

```css
.flex-container {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(n+2) {
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">item 1(long)</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 2</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 3</div>
  <div class="flex-item">item 4</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Can't set a height for the parent container because the content of items may vary in size. It needs to be dynamically set.